# Webscraping multiline cells in tables using CSS Selectors and Python

Tags: python, css, web-scraping

So I'm webscraping a page (http://canoeracing.org.uk/marathon/results/burton2016.htm) where there are multiline cells in tables:
[image]

I'm using the following code to scrape each column (the one below so happens to scrape the names):

```
import lxml.html
from lxml.cssselect import CSSSelector

# get some html
import requests

r = requests.get('http://canoeracing.org.uk/marathon/results/burton2016.htm')
# build the DOM Tree
tree = lxml.html.fromstring(r.text)
# construct a CSS Selector
sel1 = CSSSelector('body > table > tr > td:nth-child(2)')
# Apply the selector to the DOM tree.
results1 = sel1(tree)
# get the text out of all the results
data1 = [result.text for result in results1]
```

Unfortunately it's only returning the first name from each cell, not both. I've tried a similar thing on the webscraping tool Kimono and I'm able to scrape both, however I want to sent up a Python code as Kimono falls down when running over multiple webpages.

Comment: You don't need to use `CSSSelector`, you can call `tree.cssselect` as per my answer to your last question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that some of the cells contain multiple text nodes delimited by a `<br>`. In cases like this, *find all text nodes* and join them:

```
data1 = [", ".join(result.xpath("text()")) for result in rows]
```

For the provided rows in the screenshot, you would get:

```
OSCAR HUISSOON, FREJA WEBBER
ELLIE LAWLEY, RHYS TIPPINGS
ALLISON MILES, ALEX MILES
NICOLA RUDGE, DEBORAH CRUMP
```

You could have also used `.text_content()` method, but you would lose the delimiter between the text nodes, getting things like  `OSCAR HUISSOONFREJA WEBBER` in the result.